# Unable to use existing database in unit tests with Effort framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-6, effort

I am trying to write test using a database, hosted in Azure SQL, with [Effort](https://effort.codeplex.com/) framework on Entity Framework 6.

When executing the following code, an exception is thrown:

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context)
{
    EffortProviderConfiguration.RegisterProvider();
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    const string connectionString = "Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=my_catalog;User ID=user;Password=password;provider=System.Data.SqlClient";
    IDataLoader loader = new EntityDataLoader(connectionString);
    using (var ctx = new UsersDbContext(Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePersistent("cool", loader)))
    {
        var usersCount = ctx.Users.Count();
    }
}
```

Exception thrown in `Count()` execution:

> Effort.Exceptions.EffortException: Unhandled exception while trying to initialize the content of 'Table' table ---> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

The same exception is thrown when replacing `EffortProviderConfiguration.RegisterProvider()` with app.config settings.

When using exactly the same connection string for creation of the `UsersDbContext` it succeeds and the data is accessible. In addition, creating context with Effort persistent or transient mode, without connection string, works well too.

What should be done to initialize a connection with existing data from a real DB?

Comment: Hum and what happens if you use "Server" instead of "Data Source"? As far as SQL Server is concerned this is a synonym but maybe *Effort* is not aware of it...

Comment: out of interest what happens when you remove the `Data Source` from the connection string?

Comment: Hi, none of the above helped, when I change the "data source" key to "server" it complains about not supported keyword only now for the "server" key, if I delete the data source from the connection string it keeps complaining about the next key in the connection string, "Initial catalog" being unsupported.

Answer (score 6):

If like me you're confused as to why you have to give Effort a connection string at all (since it works off an in-memory database, and you provide your context a connection directly), the [documentation](https://tflamichblog.wordpress.com/2012/11/04/factory-methods-in-effort-createtransient-vs-createpersistent/) makes it a bit clearer - it's only required if you're using database-first or model-first variants of the Entity Framework, because the Entity connection string provides the information necessary for Effort to locate your model so that it can build a schema from it!! So you can safely fill the server/database/user id/password portions of the connection string with dummy names.

This also makes it clear that the custom default DbConnectionFactory approach only works for code-first, which explains the first few hours of errors I was getting... For model first or database first, you have to inject an Entity Connection into your entity class, as described [here](http://bartwullems.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/effort-entity-framework-unit-testing.html).

A useful tip - because your generated entity model class is a partial class, you can create another code file in the same assembly, give it the same namespace and make it also a partial class, and you can add the second constructor necessary for setting the EntityConnection to that code file instead, that way when you modify/recreate your entity model, the code with the custom constructor won't get deleted by the t4 template.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27789777/1518546) that gives more details about Effort only pulling out the metadata portions of the connection string so that it can create the schema.

Answer (score 3):

You are specifying connection string in wrong format. You are using ADO.NET/Linq2SQL connection string format, whenever
EntityDataLoader requires connection string that will fit EntityConnection (class from EntityFramework).
You can read about connection strings for EF here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Saying it short, your connection string should look like:

```
"Provider=System.Data.SqlClient; 
 Metadata=c:\metadata|c:\Metadata\Sql; 
 Provider Connection String='Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=60' "
```

Right now in your code you are specifying only **Provider Connection String** part.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your connection string must be provided as EF style connection string. Such as in your app.config or in your webconfig:

```
<add name="dbConnectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.YourEntityModel.csdl|res://*/Models.YourEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.YourEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=yourdatasource;initial catalog=yourdb;persist security info=True;user id=username;password=password;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    //Arrange
    //Then you can specify your connection string with its name:
    EntityConnection connection =
    Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreateTransient("name=dbConnectionString");

    //Act
    var usersCount;
    using (MyDbContext ctx= new MyDbContext(connection))
    {
        usersCount = ctx.Users.Count();
    }
    //Assert
    //Put your assert logic here:
    Assert.IsTrue(usersCount == 100);
}
```