# How would I configure Effort Testing Tool to mock Entity Framework's DbContext withOut the actual SQL Server Database up and running?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, effort

Our team's application development involves using Effort Testing Tool to mock our Entity Framework's DbContext.  However, it seems that Effort Testing Tool needs to be see the actual SQL Server Database that the application uses in order to mock our Entity Framework's DbContext which seems to going against proper Unit Testing principles.

The reason being that in order to unit test our application code by mocking anything related to Database connectivity ( for example Entity Framework's DbContext), we should Never need a Database to be up and running.

How would I configure Effort Testing Tool to mock Entity Framework's DbContext withOut the actual SQL Server Database up and running?

*
Update:

@gert-arnold We are using Entity Framework Model First approach to implement the back-end model and database.

The following excerpt is from the test code:

```
        connection = Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreateTransient("name=NorthwindModel");
        jsAudtMppngPrvdr = new BlahBlahAuditMappingProvider();
        fctry = new BlahBlahDataContext(jsAudtMppngPrvdr, connection, false);
        qryCtxt = new BlahBlahDataContext(connection, false);
        audtCtxt = new BlahBlahAuditContext(connection, false);
        mockedReptryCtxt = new BlahBlahDataContext(connection, false);
        _repository = fctry.CreateRepository<Account>(mockedReptryCtxt, null);
        _repositoryAccountRoleMaps = fctry.CreateRepository<AccountRoleMap>(null, _repository);
```

The "name=NorthwindModel" pertains to our edmx  file which contains information about our Database tables 
and their corresponding relationships.

If I remove the "name=NorthwindModel" by making the connection like the following line of code, I get an error stating that it expects an argument:

```
   connection = Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreateTransient(); // throws error
```

Could you please explain how the aforementioned code should be rewritten?

Comment: The database is only used to load data into the transient context. The alternative is to load data from CSV files, but I think a database is much more convenient.

Comment: I thought it needed to know the SQL Server Database Schema layout, and that's the only reason I created a transient EntityConnection with the connection name to the actual SQL Server Database used by our application.  Isn't it better that Effort Testing Tool knows about our SQL Server Database's schema layout so that I can create tests that would test relationships between entities? How would I configure Effort Testing Tool to mock Entity Framework's DbContext in such a way that Effort knows about our Database's schema layout but withOut the actual SQL Server Database up and running?

Comment: I don't understand what you'd want to do with the db schema. EF nor Effort provide APIs to access the schema itself (that's the whole point of an ORM). To test relationships between entities, I'd use a new context, fetch entities and test their content (references, collections).

Comment: Hey, could you please take a look at my update to the posting?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: @alex-sorokoletov I'm trying to rewrite my Effort-based test code in such a way that it will fall in line with proper Unit testing practices by actually ensuring that I don't need the database up and running when the Effort-based unit tests are being executed.  Could you please take a look at my posting?

Comment: @mosquito87 I'm trying to rewrite my Effort-based test code in such a way that it will fall in line with proper Unit testing practices by actually ensuring that I don't need the database up and running when the Effort-based unit tests are being executed. Could you please take a look at my posting, and comment by making some suggestions?

Comment: @abi-ruban I'm trying to rewrite my Effort-based test code in such a way that it will fall in line with proper Unit testing practices by actually ensuring that I don't need the database up and running when the Effort-based unit tests are being executed. Could you please take a look at my posting, and comment by making some suggestions?

Comment: I don't work with Effort (being a convinced integration test aficionado), but I simply read that you can use [CSV files as data source](http://effort.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Create%20a%20fake%20DbContext%20instance&referringTitle=Tutorials). I still don't get you when it comes to needing the database schema.

Comment: Sorry, I should not have used the term "database schema".  I meant to say that Effort Testing tool needed to be provided the Database Connection String, and needed the Database itself to be up and running so that you can conduct testing.  The problem with have the database used during testing is that it won't be proper unit testing.

Comment: @gert-Arnold Do you understand what I mean now about the database?

Comment: We're running in circles. I keep saying you don't need the database *at all*. You keep telling me you need it for something I don't get.

Comment: If you read my update above, you will see that I already tried code withOut mentioning the Database String, and it throws an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need that connection string because Effort needs to know where the EDMX file is.

The EDMX file contains all information required for creating an inmemory store with an identical schema you have in your database. You have to specify a connection string only because I thought it would be convenient if the user didn't have to mess with EDMX paths.

If you check the implementation of the CreateTransient method you will see that it merely uses the connection string to get the metadata part of it.

```
public static EntityConnection CreateTransient(string entityConnectionString, IDataLoader dataLoader)
{
    var metadata = GetEffortCompatibleMetadataWorkspace(ref entityConnectionString);
    var connection = DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient(dataLoader);
    return CreateEntityConnection(metadata, connection);
}

private static MetadataWorkspace GetEffortCompatibleMetadataWorkspace(ref string entityConnectionString)
{
    entityConnectionString = GetFullEntityConnectionString(entityConnectionString);

    var connectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(entityConnectionString);

    return MetadataWorkspaceStore.GetMetadataWorkspace(
        connectionStringBuilder.Metadata,
        metadata => MetadataWorkspaceHelper.Rewrite(
            metadata, 
            EffortProviderConfiguration.ProviderInvariantName, 
            EffortProviderManifestTokens.Version1));
}
```